# Apply check on application start to choose between different activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities but I want to apply a condition on application start, if one is true then start first activity else start second activity. Right now I am doing it by starting a third activity displaying some welcome stuff and examining the value in background..then appropriate activity gets called. I think there must be some standard way to do this. Peace.

Comment: if (something == 1) { } else {} 
thats not the point

Comment: Actually it is the point. If you simply have your MAIN/LAUNCHER check on the condition as the very first thing it does in `onCreate(...)` (after calling `super.onCreate(...)`), it can either continue or call `startActivity(...)` for the other `Activity` and immediately call `finish()`. That way the first `Activity` will never be seen if the condition dictates the second `Activity` should be started - no need for a third `Activity`.

Comment: Maybe you can post it as answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Converted my comment as an answer and padded it slightly for future users of stackoverflow

Comment: Actually I just noticed Pavel Dudka's answer is very much like mine and he got there first. You could accept either mine or his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to specify starting activity in manifest, you can always start first activity, check your condition on `onCreate()` and if you need to start second one - start second one and call `finish()` for the first activity.

Otherwise usually people use splash activity to check all the conditions at the startup (which is your current solution).

Comment: You can also have a no-UI activity that performs the test, rather than fussing around with a splash screen. For example, this sample app checks to make sure that we are running on a device with the Maps SDK add-on, via a `Theme.NoDisplay` `LAUNCHER` activity: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkMapless

Comment: I am going with Squonk's approach.

Comment: :P actually I got the idea after reading his comment..now they look same to me ;)

Comment: @PavelDudka : I posted my comment to the original question (and my answer) before I read your answer properly. I posted another comment to the original question saying you'd already suggested the basic idea. I'm leaving my answer standing as it includes example code for any future SO users who might be looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a third `Activity` to check the condition.

If you simply have your MAIN/LAUNCHER `Activity` check on the condition as the very first thing it does in `onCreate(...)` (but after calling `super.onCreate(...)`), it can either continue or call `startActivity(...)` for the other `Activity` and immediately call `finish()` to self-terminate.

That way the first `Activity` will never be seen if the condition dictates the second `Activity` should be started.

Example..

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Don't even set the content view at this point
        // we want to be invisible for the moment

        // Pseudo-code check for condition
        if (!runMe) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else {
            // Continue as normal
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```